# See where .NET executable is looping, on user machine

Tags: .net, remote-debugging

When my app enters a long or infinite loop on my dev PC, I break it in the VS debugger which tells me what it's doing. I'd like to do that in a simple fashion on user PCs too, to help with debugging.

I was thinking something like this:

- In the app, run a separate thread that waits on some sort of interprocess pipe, and, upon receiving anything from it, logs the current stacktrace of the main thread. (using Thread.GetCompressedStack() ?)
- Ship a helper exe, e.g. `break.exe` that, when ran, connects to the other process and writes something to the pipe.

Then if a user reports an app freeze, I can tell them to try running break.exe.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: The link here might be useful : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/11/28/snapshot.aspx.  I'd avoid adding new comms pipes in your process if you can.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options.

- Task manager lets you create a dump of any running process. The dump can be inspected on your dev machine. You can inspect the stacks of all the threads by loading the dump into the debugger (I recommend using WinDbg/SOS for this). This option doesn't require any additional installs on the user machine.
- [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) lets you inspect the threads of a running process. If you have a repeating loop, you may be able to detect that by looking at the stacks.
- [WinDbg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009) (with SOS which is part of the framework) can be xcopy deployed to the user machine. You can attach to the process and examine or take a dump of the process memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z9k5ydz.aspx) for outputting the debug information. The text of the debug output can be caught with e.g. Sysinternals' [DbgView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647).

Alternatively, you can make a special debug build for the user, which would dump all the necessary information into a file in the user's %APPDATA%.